# lambda expression to fetch multiple array element with special characters

Tags: c#, lambda, substring

How to get a list of values which has special characters in it using lambda expression?

I have a list of text-items in an array named values and want the list of text-items containing special characters from it.

```
var specialCharacters = new string[] { ",", ":", "=" };
```

I tried couple of times and it didn't worked.

```
var ans = Array.FindAll(values, value => value.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.None).Length > 0);
```

alternately I was tried

```
var ans2 = values.Where(value => (value.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.None)).Length > 0).ToList();
```

Both expression didn't worked for me. Output is same as the array "values".

Comment: Can you give the sample inputs? If you can have the expected outputs, and the actual outputs, it will be better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use  this

```
 var ans2 = values.Where(value => (value.Split(specialCharacters, StringSplitOptions.None)).Length > 1).ToList();
```

check the length with 1 .
because if special Characters not present in `value`, then also array will be created with length of 1 having the `value` at its 0 th index.

Answer (score 0):

While @Viplock's answer is good, I don't think splitting all the strings is the most performant way to go about it. Consider something like this:

```
char[] specialCharacters = { ',', ':', '=' };
IEnumerable<string> result = values.Where(s => ContainsSpecialCharacter(s, specialCharacters));
```

...with `ContainsSpecialCharacter` defined like so:

```
private static bool HasSpecialCharacter(string s, char[] specialCharacters)
{
    return specialCharacters.Any(specialCharacter => s.Contains(specialCharacter));
}
```

I also changed `SpecialCharacters` into an array of `char`s, but that will work either way.

**Caveat**: I could be wrong about my performance claim; I haven't actually done any measurements. :-)

Comment: Its just a test code. By the way the suggestion to use array of char is good.

Comment: If it's test code, brevity is definitely the way to go.